# getDefaultDestination() return null value

Tags: java, spring, jms, javabeans

I created dynamic web project in eclipse(Kepler).In my application, I used Spring,JMS,ActiveMQ & JSF. In my java class use following code to get defaultdestination define in bean xml.

```
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;


public class JmsReceiver {
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

public JmsTemplate getjmsTemplate() {

    return jmsTemplate;

}

public void setjmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {

    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;

}

public void processMessage() {


    System.out.println("DefaultDestination :"+jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestination());


}

}
```

My bean definition is :

```
<bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"></bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">  
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>
<property name="defaultDestination"><ref bean="defaultDestination"/></property>
<property name="defaultDestinationName" value="myqueue"></property>  
</bean>
```

But when running 'DefaultDestination: null' .
Pls guide me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="demoQueueDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg><!-- 设置消息队列的名字 -->
         <value>Jaycekon</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>   

ActiveMQDestination destination = (ActiveMQDestination) jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestination();
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " 向队列" + destination.getPhysicalName() + "发送消息---------------------->" + msg);
```